# WinJS 3.0 Apps on LG and Samsung Smart TVs

Tags: winjs

Today i've tried the WinJS 3.0 (Javascript Library from Microsoft) on my LG SmartTV with WebOS and works perfect. But i've a problem:

I' want to use my TV Remote to control de UI. I need to do this from WinJS app? or this is an implementation of the LG HTML/JS SDK?

I' want to do same with Samsung Smart TV.

Please advice

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinJS itself doesn't have any functionality particular to hardware devices. It's a general library that contains UI controls and things like promises and data binding, so anything you'd do specific to SmartTVs would have to come from those manufacturer's SDKs. I would imagine those SDKs would have the ability to raise events in the app that you can then handle to manage the WinJS controls used in the app's UI.